# Prevent others from seeing stats of URLs shortened with Google's URL shortener via API

Tags: google, url, url-shorteners

Using Java API, I am generating shortened URLs with goo.gl

But it's showing the analytics information to anyone who is accessing the URL by adding .info extension.

I want to secure this so that the analytics can be seen by only me.

Is this supported by Google Shortener service?.

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear due to lack of information provided (examples work great, i.e curl head responses or console logs of some sort.). Additionally if related to API programming it is possibly off topic on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: @SimonHayter, I have updated my question

Comment: It would still be nice to get an example URL and how to modify it to see the stats using the `.info` trick.